# Where can I find neighbours for testnet?

Tags: iri-node, node, testnet

I want to run my node in the testnet for testing and learning purposes. Where can I find neighbours for it? Is there some kind of public list of public testnet nodes?

Comment: +1. This question really needs some good answers. I am also stuck on getting neighbors for testnet.

Answer (score 3):

you can find a #testnet channel on the new IOTA Discord https://discord.gg/5spymQ, ask there and you will probably find people to connect with.

There is a #testnet channel on the IOTA Slack also, but this tchat will be closed and people are currently migrating on the Discord.

Comment: Actually I asked this question on both slack and discord before publishing the question on StackExchange. Nobody answered me there, so I decided maybe I'll be more lucky here.

Comment: keep trying on Discord, this is your best chance. Maybe you can try in #tanglemath and #cord-dev-answer

Comment: Same here. It's quite difficult to find any neighbours.

Answer (score 3):

You can visit https://nodesharing.wisewolf.de/, which can automatically assign you testnet or mainnet neighbours for the Chrysalis network (IOTA 1.5, as currently live).

Answer (score 2):

Neighbors on the test network are difficult to obtain and unstable. It is recommended to use official test nodes, especially when your node would have have a dynamic IP address, would not be reachable from the public Internet, or would not be online 24/7.